# col-xs not working for media screen less than 768px

Tags: html, css, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

```css
body {
  margin-left: 50px !important;
  margin-right: 50px !important;
}

.section {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.69);
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.outer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 82%;
}

.table-parent {
  display: table;
}

.table-child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.section:hover {
  color: #ececeb;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.table-child .fa {
  padding-right: 6px !important;
}

.section:hover .item-overlay.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}

.item-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s, right 0.3s, bottom 0.3s, left 0.3s;
}

.item-overlay.bottom {
  bottom: 100%;
}

.table-child p {
  display: inline-block;
  text-rendering: auto;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333 !important;
}

#AddProduct {
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .col-xs-12 {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <div class="row outer">
    <div class="row inner">

      <div class="clearfix parent-div">
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section table-parent">
            <div class="item-overlay bottom"></div>
            <h4 class="table-child"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
              <p>ADD A PRODUCT</p>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section table-parent">
            <div class="item-overlay bottom"></div>
            <h4 class="table-child"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
              <p>EDIT A PRODUCT</p>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </a>

        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#removeModal">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section table-parent">
            <div class="item-overlay bottom"></div>
            <h4 class="table-child"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
              <p>REMOVE A PRODUCT</p>
            </h4>
          </div>
        </a>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section table-parent">
          <div class="item-overlay bottom"></div>
          <h4 class="table-child"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
            <p>USER'S LIST</p>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section table-parent">
          <div class="item-overlay bottom"></div>
          <h4 class="table-child"><i class="fa fa-sort" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
            <p>ORDERS</p>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section table-parent">
          <div class="item-overlay bottom"></div>
          <h4 class="table-child"><i class="fa fa-power-off" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;
            <p>LOGOUT</p>
          </h4>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I am using Bootstrap v3. The divs are not taking 100% width in mobile devices with col-xs-12. Code is working fine for medium and small screens but retaining the 50% width for screens less than 768. Here is the link to the screenshot of the behaviour.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZirJH.png)

Gone through all other available solutions but none worked for me.

I don't know how to put this into words but I am getting the desired output on resizing the browser window but the code doesn't seem to work on the actual device and the web inspector. Screenshot of the device [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLixR.png)

Additionally I tried with !important as well at the end of css but facing the same problem.

Comment: Could you please share some of the css and html please, otherwise we'd just be guessing, for a quick hack you could add `!important` after the width in `.col-xs-12`

Comment: I think the problem is the sequence off ur classes. Try this sequence xs, sm, md, lg

Comment: The issue might be the higher pixel density on newer iPhones. I think the answer here will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933143/css-media-queries-pixel-density-desktop-and-mobile-devices

Comment: That worked perfectly! The viewport meta tag was missing. Thank you! @BSMP

Answer (score 2):

Taken from comment of [chetan kalra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6636256/chetan-kalra) and posting answer for quick reference for others. I also faced this issue and found viewport meta tag was missing. Adding below line did the trick.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```